# how to delete all element of a html webpage having some specific style value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i want to remove all div's of a webpage having same style.
all of the div will be having this style (given below). how can i remove all of them using jquery or JavaScript.

PS: i can not add a class in this div.

```
<div style="box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0px 2px 5px; line-height: 12px;
border: 1px solid rgb(102, 85, 102); padding: 2px; font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 400; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
white-space: nowrap; border-radius: 3px 3px 0px; position: absolute;
right: 0px; bottom: 0px; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(249, 249, 249) 0%,
rgb(238, 238, 238) 52%, rgb(249, 249, 249) 52%, rgb(227, 227, 227) 63%,
rgb(238, 238, 238) 63%, rgb(227, 227, 227) 100%);">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any specific styling rule in there you want to find?

Comment: this is same for all, i just want to delete all div's having this style.

Comment: Could you give a more complete example of the HTML, as in showing the surrounding elements? It would probably be easier to find this element by DOM traversal instead of filtering by that mess of CSS

Comment: Why you cannot add class to div?

Comment: how about using data-element? if you can't use class.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Nh37KUu7

i need to remove this whole div from html page it is one of the layer of google map that shows bus number of directions. as there is no way we can remove bus numbers from directions i needed to remove this html code.
i hope you understood what i am trying to say.

Comment: it is generated by google map automatically.

Comment: You could have posted it in jsfiddle.net or plunker so that we could have tried some methods.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/091qv6w7/ this is jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per I understood, you will need to verify each style and then delete the div, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnDeleteDivs").on("click", function(e){
    var divs = $("div");
    divs.each(function(i){
        if($(this).css("line-height") == "12px" && $(this).css("border") == "1px solid rgb(102, 85, 102)"){
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thonyrg/u2bdf7s8/)

Comment: thanks it works i used 

    var divs = $("div");
    divs.each(function(i){
    if($(this).css("z-index") == "107"){
    console.log("this is div");
    console.log(this);
    $(this).remove();
    }
    });

i used a common property that was z-index.

Comment: Brilliant. Glad I could help! :)